# sklearn.train_test_split-test_size causes ValueError inconsistent numbers of samples

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression, valueerror

I am having a super weird problem. Below, I am showing my code.

**Code:**

```
#The df here is a data with 208 samples, 60 feature(0-59th) The 60th column is the label "R" OR "M" which I m turning it to 1 and 0.

df[60] = [1 if x == 'R' else 0 for x in df[60]]

X = df.loc[:,[x for x in range(60)]]
y = df[60]

print(X.shape) #(208, 60)
print(y.shape) #(208,)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state=123)


#.... this is where causes the error message. Where I have to calculate the r2 score after using linear regression. 

print(r2_score(y_test,acc))
#....

Error message:

ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [42, 60]

*********************
print(y_test.shape) #### (42,)
print(acc.shape) #### (60,60) -> this is the predicted after running linear regression on the data.
```

Could anyone please please help me? Thank you so much.

Comment: `acc` can't be a multi-dimensional array. it has to be a single dimensional with shape `(42,)`. Can you post your fit and predict codes?

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you sure you want to solve your problem with linear regression? I mean you basically have 60 features as input and you are trying to predict whether or not these 60 features have as label R or M. I would classify this problem as a classification problem. Regression returns as ouptut a value, however in your case you are interested in the class "R" or "M" (you assigned yourself 0 and 1 as targets)
2. R^2 is only useful for regression (you should replace it with accuracy)
3. You need to post the code reponsible for producing a (60,60) vector. It seems rather odd. Did you try to predict 60 values for an input of 60? What you were supposed to do is (under the assumption that you still want to use linear regression -- ill advised)

> ```
> reg = LinearRegression().fit(X_train, y_train)
> print(reg.score(X_train, y_train)) #to get R^2 score for train
> print(reg.predict(X_test)) #to get predictions for test which you may use to calculate your r^2 (once again ill advised -- treat it as classification imo)
> ```

Just remember your shapes are supposed to be after train_test split:

X_train: (166, 60)

y_train: (166,)

X_test: (42, 60)

y_test: (42,)

prediction for train: (166,)

prediction for test: (42,)